# Stumped by a singular value decomposition problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

The question I'm working on goes like this (from Strang's *Linear Algebra* 4th edition):

Find the SVD from the eigenvectors $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2$ of $A^TA$ and $A\vec{v}_i=\sigma_i\vec{u}_i$: $$\mathbf{Fibonacci\; matrix}\quad A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I've calculated $A^TA$ to be $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, and its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which means that the diagonal matrix in the SVD is $\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}&0\\0&\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\end{bmatrix}$.

And that's where I lose it. My professor rushed through SVD, so I still don't fully understand the process, and the simple examples we did in class don't help much here. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Edit: I've worked out that the unit eigenvectors of $A^TA$ are $\vec{v}_1=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5+\sqrt{5}}}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v}_2=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5-\sqrt{5}}}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Given an *m* $\times$ *n* matrix *A*, you want to find a factorization *A* = *U* Σ *V*$^*$ such that *U* is an *m* $\times$ *m* unitary matrix, Σ is an *m* $\times$ *n* rectangular diagonal matrix with non-negative real numbers on the diagonal, and *V*$^*$ is the conjugate transpose of an *n* $\times$ *n* unitary matrix *V*.

To clarify the above for a square matrix *A*, let us continue your example.  You already know how to find Σ.

You also have done the work to find *V*: The columns of *V* are your unit eigenvectors—in the first column, put the unit eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue you chose for the first diagonal entry of Σ.

Finally, calculate *U* by solving the factorization equation to get *U* = *AV* Σ$^{-1}.$  (Note that the transpose of a unitary matrix is also its inverse.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I appreciate that you didn't just give me the answer and tried instead to guide me toward it on my own. I ended up solving that problem a few days after posting the question, however, and I didn't know at the time that I was allowed to answer my own questions (or even that that was a feature of the site). What's proper site protocol as to what I should do now? Accept your answer? Post my solution as an answer? Both? Something else entirely?

Comment: @RobertHoward If you like, you may post your solution as a second answer to mine.  You should accept the answer, if any, that was most helpful in finding your solution; if you post a solution, do not be afraid to accept it.  Finally, you should upvote any useful answer except that you are not allowed to upvote yours.